# how to make oozie schedule with holiday excluded

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

we have source files are arrived in hdfs every day except holidays.
our oozie coordinator watch these files to start every day. I do not want the oozie to run on holidays defined. How to do that. Coodinator should not timeout if it is holiday.

Comment: one solution I am thinking right now is to have a workflow as the first wf each day to check if it is a holiday today (from external api call, search a holiday file). 

If yes, it will update all the workflow coordinator (bundle)'s pausetime to today (in order to find all coordinator, we need a java api action to collect all coordinator/bundle jobid in the scope), with command or api, such as oozie 
    job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -change 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe -value pausetime=2011-12-01T05:00Z

Comment: Or, use that extra WF to generate an empty set of files on holidays, so that the file-triggered WF can start & do nothing that matters & update their status. Business as usual.

Comment: Generate extra files may not work. Since we may have read only permission on source file folders. Empty file could also fire false alert

Comment: Looks like you are stuck in a complicated mess then. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is run job regularly and exclude all the job actions through switch case using decision nodes for holidays. For this start to java action which will check if this is holiday, propagate this value to decision action and then decide if the required actions will run or not for this value.(oozie supports propagation of value in workflow from one action to other). For each of the two scenario provide different message for your confirmation, 'todays holiday required actions skipped' else 'No holidays job succeeded'.